# Heatmaps with multiple dataset + border

Tags: highcharts, heatmap

Is it possible to plot 2 datasets on heatmap, and differentiate between them by surrounding the second dataset with a border?

Comment: What would this look like?

Comment: A regular heatmap table with several rows, where the top rows are the first dataset, and the bottom rows are the second dataset. The rows of this second datasets have a border around it.

Answer (score 1):

You can define border for particular point, like single field.

```
{x:9, y:4,  value:91, borderWidth:10, borderColor:'red'}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/66Lcu9rr/